# Time machine Detection over VPN via DNS-SD?

Tags: networking, vpn, time-machine, mdns, netatalk

I'm running a local DNS server in my home network ([dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)) and a [Netatalk](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/) instance for Time Machine over WiFi. Due to limitations of Multicast over my VPN setup, my Time Machine does not get recognized over my IPSec Tunnel, because the Zeroconf / mDNS detection fails.

[DNS-SD](http://dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html) seems to be a solution for this, since I automatically get my local DNS over the VPN tunnel, but I cannot figure out, which entries have to be configured for this.

Which DNS entries have to be configured?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit too much to repeat here, but a definitive write-up of how to configure a unicast DNS server to support DNS-SD is available here:

http://dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html